# Why do I have 3 batteries In Windows 7 Power Management?

Tags: windows-7, power-management, battery

Look at this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SzW0j.png]

I do not remember having 3 batteries. Is this a bug?

Comment: What the, you have a Turbo Boost option?? How?!

Comment: No, it is just a power plan's name.

Answer (score 6):

I'm *assuming* that this is a laptop.

Some laptops have multiple expansion bays that can take drives and batteries.  The laptop is telling Windows 7 that there are multiple bays that can support batteries and that they are not present; nothing to worry about.